# How to write in second-order logic that a relation is divisible by another?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, second-order-logic

Suppose we have the relation of being 100 meters apart, R. And the relation of being 20 meters apart, M. Then whatever two coordinates a,b are 100m apart (Rab), there are four other coordinates, say c, d, e, f so that Mac, Mcd, Mde, Mef, Mfb. This can be written in FOL with identity as:

∀x∀y(Rxy ⊃ ∃t∃u∃v∃w(Mxt & Mtu & Muv & Mvw & Mwy & x≠t & t ≠ u & u ≠ v & v ≠ w & w ≠ y))

Now suppose I only want to make the statement that R is divisible by M. So without specifying the 100m and 20m, we want to say that there is a natural number n, such that there are n-1 coordinates different than the two coordinates for which R holds, and n M relations hold between them. How can this be written in FOL or SOL?

**Edit**
I think I found it:

∀x∀y(Rxy ⊃ Sxy);

∀x∀y(Sxy ⊃ (∃Z∃t( ( Z = ∅ & t = y) ∨ ( Mxt & Zty & (Zty ⊃ Sty ∨ Z = M) & x≠t & t≠y )))

So we introduce a new relation S (for "separable") for which we state that it can be divided by a new coordinate t into an M relation and another relation that can be either the empty set, the M relation or is itself separable.

Any opinions would be appreciated.

**Second edit**
Thanks to Derek Elkins, my first solution was proved wrong. However, I found this first-order solution

∀x∀y(Rxy ⊃ Sxy);

∀x∀y(Sxy ⊃ ( Mxy ∨ ∃t(Mxt & Sty & x≠t & t≠y) )

It states that R is separable (S), meaning that it either implies M or there is another coordinate such that it has an M relation with x and another separable relation with y.

Any opinions would be appreciated.

**Third edit**

My second proposal was wrong too. See correct answer below

Comment: What stops me from choosing a model where $S$ always holds, in which case the first statement holds trivially and the second holds by simply choosing $Z$ and $t$ as $\varnothing$ and $y$. At this point, nothing at all is being said about $M$.

Comment: For your second solution, again choose $S$ to always hold, then you simply get $\forall x,y.M(x,y)\lor(\exists t.M(x,t)\land x\neq t\land t\neq y)$. This says nothing at all about $R$. In both of your proposed solutions, I imagine you are driven by a (false) intuition that $S$ should contain only what it can be *proven* to contain. That is not how FOL works. I'm allowed to choose any interpretation of the relation symbols I want as long as they are consistent with the axioms. To know whether a theory means what you want you have to consider *all* interpretations, not just the minimal.

Comment: In general, FOL has difficultly saying some predicate holds for some things *and nothing else* at least when whether the predicate holds for one thing depends on whether it holds for another. (More technically, FOL can't characterize inductively defined sets.) This is why, even with an *infinite* number of axioms, the first-order theory of Peano arithmetic fails to characterize the natural numbers. The second-order version of Peano arithmetic achieves this (with respect to full semantics) with just a handful of axioms.

Comment: You're right, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this in first-order logic. One way of formulating this would be to say that $R$ is in the transitive closure<sup>1</sup> of $M$ (i.e. $\forall x,y.R(x,y)\to M^+(x,y)$), but FOL can't express [transitive closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#In_logic_and_computational_complexity). This isn't a proof, but it is suggestive.

We can express the transitive closure of a first-order predicate in second-order logic. We just formulate it as the smallest relation that contains the generating relation and is transitive. Write $\mathsf{Trans}_M(S)$ for the expression $$(\forall x,y.M(x,y)\to S(x,y))\land(\forall x,y,z.S(x,y)\land S(y,z)\to S(x,z))$$ which states that $S$ is a transitive relation that contains $M$. Then $$\mathsf{Trans}_M(M^+)\land\forall S.\mathsf{Trans}_M(S)\to(\forall x,y.M^+(x,y)\to S(x,y))$$ states that $M^+$ is the transitive closure of $M$. We can then use the formula from the first paragraph and wrap the whole thing in an $\exists M^+$. That is,$$\begin{align}\exists M^+.\mathsf{Trans}_M(M^+)&\land(\forall S.\mathsf{Trans}_M(S)\to(\forall x,y.M^+(x,y)\to S(x,y)))\\&\land(\forall x,y.R(x,y)\to M^+(x,y))\end{align}$$

<sup>1</sup> You can add reflexivity if you want.

Comment: This doesn't say $R\subseteq M^n$ for some $n$, but rather for each $x$ and $y$ there is an $n$ such that $R(x,y)\to M^n(x,y)$. In other words, each pair is joined by a chain, but the chains don't have to be the same length for every pair.